# Indexes vs full scans, how do i determine which to use and when

Tags: oracle

Is there a rule of thumb on when to use full scans rather than indexes? I am new to oracle and am still struggling to wrap my mind around performance tuning. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intent of the optimizer is to make these decisions for you. Granted it won't always be right, but generally I'll let the optimizer do all the heavy lifting for me, and only worry about the issues where it went awry and I had to "intervene" so to speak.

But in terms of full scan versus index, I'd encourage you not to think in these terms, simply because your customer and hence your applications don't care. What customers care about is response time, so the driving factor here should always be response time.

If for query 1, a full scan is *faster* than an index scan, then the full scan is the better option. That doesn't make a full scan better "always" or somehow "philosophically" or "technically" better than an index scan. It simply means for this query, the full scan was best.

If for another query, the index is better, then by all means, we should use the index.

Its common to see advisories in books and blog posts, saying "Look for TABLE ACCESS FULL in the plan - thats bad", and similar. That is BS in my opinion. Whatever execution plan gives you the best performance for your query, is the best one... no matter whether it uses index scans, full scans, or any other form of optimizer path.

If you'd like a more holistic look at SQL tuning, I've written a four-part series here https://connor-mcdonald.com/2019/10/24/the-holistic-sql-tuning-series/

Comment: Not to mention that `STORAGE FULL` is a bit less evil than `TABLE ACCESS FULL`;)